# Is EOS based on an Ethereum client? (geth, parity, etc)

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

Do we know if EOS is based on code contributed by the Ethereum community? Is it possible that they will "steal" a lot of the open source projects that have been developed for Ethereum?

I am not, and will not, invest in EOS. Only wondering if it is based in solidity.

Comment: no. it's their own blockchain which is not ethereum compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOS is a genuine new BlockChain infrastructure with lots of insights from Ethereum. But, all EOS source codes are totally independent from Ethereum.

You can check their core repositories at GitHub: https://github.com/EOSIO/

Additionally, now there is a Stack Exchange site dedicated for EOS: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/